# binding a tree component to a grid layout in oracle adf

Tags: jsf, data-binding, oracle-adf, data-controls

I am currently working on an oracle adf application and stuck in a task.
Actually I have a datacontrol generated through java bean that have two function getAllProductCategories and getProductsByName(String name).I have made a tree through getAllProductCategories and through backend bind a method action getProductsByName(String name) on the basis of tree action listener getProductsByName(String name) is calling successfully but the data in the grid layout is not changing.I want to show the products in grid layout on the basis of the name of the tree node that has been clicked.

Can any body help me in this regard and give me some examples.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to set the partialTrigger attribute for the component which are listening to the changes in the other component. The value of the partialTrigger attribute would be the ID of the component to which it is listening.

Can you post your code so that we can have a look and help you out?